# Grunt read file with replacements in a template

Tags: javascript, file, templates, replace, gruntjs

I am using `grunt-template` and I am reading a file with this statement:

```
<%= grunt.file.read("someFile.js") %>
```

Now I need to make some text replacements in `someFile.js`. How can I achieve this in a sane way? Can I define an own function for this?

Answer (score 0):

`grunt.template` will replace all from `<%=` to `%>`.
So using `<%= grunt.file.read("someFile.js") %>` template you will replace all file content.
It will be better to read file sync by node.js via `fs.readFileSync`, replace something in it and use `writeFileSync` to save changes.

Comment: Isn't `grunt.file.read` already sync? I guess so. I found out that `grunt.file.read('file.js').replace('foo', 'bar')` works within the template syntax, but that isn't really a sane solution, as I don't want to pollute my template with this.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be exactly what you're looking for but you could achieve this using Grunt Preprocess:

https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess

In this case:

```
var configValue = '/* @echo FOO */';
```

/* @echo FOO */ would be replaced with the FOO value defined in the Gruntfile.

Comment: I am a bit confused by this, how should I apply it with my use case?

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't work for your use case, but you place the /* @echo */ vars in your JS file where you want to be able to alter it (e.g. for different server environments) and replace with the appropriate variable in the grunt task

Comment: Ah I see now, unfortunately I can't use it this way. Thanks anyway